# Ubuntu Touch - Login screen

Tags: ubuntu-touch, login-screen

Is there a way that I can set up my Ubuntu Touch Tablet login screen to rotate when the rotational lock is not on? When I have my tablet on its rest the login screen is upside down. So I enter my password upside down and when done, the screen direction will correct itself.

Comment: Looks like a bug and/or design decision: http://askubuntu.com/questions/757164/ubuntu-touch-lockscreen-and-app-home-screen-stuck-in-landscape

Comment: Was thinking that myself. I will have a look and see if I can raise it.

Comment: This has been logged under - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/1576962

Comment: The status of this has been moved to 'Confirmed' as it is affecting multiple users.

Comment: Now there is a comment on my bug saying that it is a duplicate of https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-devices-system-image/+bug/1573229 As yet, there is no update on the new defect.